# How to display data from selected ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a page with a list of Service and I made it a clickable button

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(item.ServiceName, "QueueInfo", 
                     new { id = item.ServiceId}, new { @class = "button btn btn-default" })
}
```

Whenever I click 1 of this it redirects to my "QueueInfo controller" and here's the code for that.

```
public ActionResult QueueInfo()
{
    ViewBag.ServiceId = new SelectList(db.Services, "ServiceId", "ServiceName");
    return View();
}
```

How can I change the value of my dropdown list depending on what Service i Click from the first code? is that even possible?

Comment: Are those clickable buttons on the `QueueInfo` view or on a different view?

Answer (score 0):

SelectList has a property known as selectedValue , you can pass your selected id in to it.

```
public ActionResult QueryInfo(int? id)
{
    ViewBag.ServiceId = new SelectList(db.Services, "ServiceId", "ServiceName", id);
    return View();
}
```

Comment: wait, what about i dont want to make it as a dropdown? can it just be a readonly